# Where would I find C# flocking tutorials?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, ai

Been looking for a while now and finding it difficult to find a good tutorial...

Where would I find a good tutorial on how to implement flocking in a C# XNA game? Something easy to understand .. for beginners!

Cheers!

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it. Asking for tutorials is just going to get you a list of responses, which you will probably have seen if you've done your research (as seen with your first answer). You should ask a specific question about the flocking algorithm that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN offer a great project sample for flocking. Here is the
[link](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/flocking) Hopefully, that will get your started

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ive already come across this, just looking for a simple tutorial, rather than a code example, that talks you through how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the comments. They are very useful in terms of whats going on (Thats how I understood what was coded). There is a good post on stackoverflow about resources for flocking :  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727375/what-are-some-good-resources-on-flocking-and-swarm-algorithms)

Comment: Still finding it difficult, will try digging more, thanks for the response!